# Unable to Incorporate Negative Samples or Background Images for Training the Object Detection Model in MediaPipe

Tags: machine-learning, object-detection, mediapipe

I am facing an issue where the object detection model in MediaPipe ignores the inclusion of negative samples during training. For instance, I have a dataset containing 500 images with object labels and an additional 200 images labeled as negative samples. However, when checking the training data size, it only displays 'train_data size: 500' instead of the expected 700. I have attempted two different methods of annotating negative samples in my dataset, using the following XML formats:

```
<annotation verified="yes">
   <folder>images</folder>
   <filename>10.jpeg</filename>
   <path>/content/jpeg_images/train/images/10.jpeg</path>
   <source>
    <database>Unknown</database>
   </source>
   <size>
    <width>640</width>
    <height>480</height>
    <depth>3</depth>
   </size>
   <segmented>0</segmented>
</annotation>
```

```
<annotation verified="yes">
    <folder>images</folder>
    <filename>1.jpeg</filename>
    <path>/content/jpeg_images/train/images/1.jpeg</path>
    <source>
        <database>Unknown</database>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>599</width>
        <height>399</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>background</name>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>0</xmin>
            <ymin>0</ymin>
            <xmax>0</xmax>
            <ymax>0</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

both are getting ignored

The expected behavior is for the MediaPipe object detection model to seamlessly process and train with negative samples, ensuring their inclusion in the training dataset. This capability should lead to a well-rounded model capable of accurately detecting objects and distinguishing them from negative instances during inference